# Don't display pushd/popd stack across several bash scripts (quiet pushd/popd)

Tags: bash, output, built-in

Each time I use pushd or popd, it print the stack to standard output. How not to do so?

I don't want to do `pushd > /dev/null` each time because I have a lot of scripts calling each other.

Maybe a nice override will do it, but I'll need to override these builtins only in my scripts, and then restore the correct behavior.

Comment: If someone came across this question wanting to silence a single occurrence you can replace `pushd` and `popd` with `cd` and `cd ~-`. `~-` is a _tilde expansion_ that sets to _$OLDPWD_.

Comment: @AgustínLado `cd -` also works. Not sure which version is more compatible with wide range of systems.

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim: Without tilde it prints the folder name (at least on Ubuntu 18.04 running on WSL).

Comment: If you have a sequence of commands between a `cd some/path` and a `cd -` or `cd "${return_wd}"` or something similar, consider grouping the commands in between into a function and use a subshell like `(cd some/path; your_commands_here)`. The directory navigation back to the old PWD is implied at the end of the subshell. Also works for command substitutions.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You could add

```
pushd () {
    command pushd "$@" > /dev/null
}

popd () {
    command popd "$@" > /dev/null
}
```

to the top of each script. This is probably the minimum amount of work it will take to solve your problem.

Comment: If you want to silence errors (e.g. no such directory) too, then you can use `&>` instead of `>`

Comment: Be careful when silencing errors: you could create a hard to diagnose failure at a later date. Make sure you check for a not-OK return code and respond to it accordingly.

Comment: This is the least invasive option.

Comment: You can add `set -e` to the beginning of both functions and `set +e` to the end or just `set -e` at the beginning of the script to exit the script if an exit code != 0 is encountered. This also works in the shebang, e. g. `#!/bin/bash -e`. Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: @xdevs23 I don't recommend the use of `set -e`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105.

Comment: @chepner valid points, I think it's okay to add it to pushd and popd though. If those fail the script shall exit or it could do things you might not want it to do.

Comment: Might be better to do `|| exit 1` or `|| exit $?` instead though, in that case you can't catch the errors, so maybe `|| return $?` is even better?

Comment: It's up to the caller of the function to decide whether to exit the script or not, just like with the built-in commands.

Comment: @xdevs23 `|| exit $?` is equivalent to just `|| exit`. Same for `return`.

Comment: don't really need "$@" for popd - it takes no arguments in bash.

Comment: @bmacnaughton It doesn't have any *required* arguments; it accepts `-n` and a whole family of `-N` and `+N` (for an integer `N`) arguments.

Comment: good point @chepner. i'd just never used them but they're more likely in a script.

Answer (score 14):

In zsh you can `setopt PUSHDSILENT`. Put this in your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Or use `popd -q` (quiet).

Comment: popd doesn't have `-q` option

Comment: @MarekN: the previous comment of "popd -q" was referring to zsh, not bash, even though the original question was tagged as wanting bash answers, not zsh.

Comment: This is a nice comment or a tangent to an answer, but it doesn't belong as a standalone answer to a question that isn't asking about `zsh`.

Answer (score 3):

In your .profile file (what ever it is called in your system) add:

```
pushd () {
    command pushd "$@" > /dev/null
}

popd () {
    command popd "$@" > /dev/null
}

export pushd popd
```

Comment: This affects entire of the system... personally, I don't recommend this way . .